# Prompt input on double click on cell in google sheet using google script

Tags: google-apps-script, input, google-sheets, prompt

I'd like to prompt an input box when I double click on a cell in Google Sheet.
The perfect example is when you protect a range in Google Sheet, whoever tries to double click on the protected range gets a prompted message box. I want to do the same with a input box instead.

The simplified version of the code I use is:

```
function editCell(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("*** SEARCH ***");
  var lule = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Edit Contact ', '('+lule+')', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Contacts");
    ss.insertRow(1)
    ss.getRange(1,1).setValue(response.getResponseText());
  }
  else if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    Logger.log('no');
  }
  else {
  Logger.log('nope');
  }
}
```

Thanks

---

UPDATED CODE

```
function setCell(){
  //e.source.toast('flag1');
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  if(sh.getSheetName() == "Contacts" == true){
    Logger.log('nope');
  }
  else if(sh.getSheetName() == "*** SEARCH ***" == true){

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("*** SEARCH ***")
    var cel = sheet.getActiveCell();    
    var val = cel.getValue();    
    var row = cel.getRow();
    var col = cel.getColumn();
    cel.setValue("");
    var lule = sheet.getRange(row,col).getValue();
    var line = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,1).getValue();
    sheet.getRange("A4").setValue(line)
    sheet.getRange("A5").setValue(col)

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Contacts");
        ss.getRange(line+4,col).setValue(val);

  }
}
```

Comment: What is `ss.addrow(1)` meant to do? `addRow()` isn't a method of the `Sheet` class ([return type of `getSheetByName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)).

Comment: I meant `insertRow(1)` which means to add only 1 row at the row #1. It could add a row at row X, Y or Z.

Comment: `insertRow()` is also not a method. Please read the documentation and test your code before asking others to help as the documentation contains the methods you need. I think you're looking for is [`Ui.alert()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alert(String)).

Comment: Would `insertRows()` satisfy you better?
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertRows(Integer)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to be funny. Stackoverflow is a forum for developers to help each other and guessing method names when the documentation is there leaves additional, unnecessary work for the people trying to help you. Check out the [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I completely understand. I appreciate the time and your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FOUND A WORKAROUND

onEdit triggers this function

```
function setCell(){
  //e.source.toast('flag1');
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("*** SEARCH ***")
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Contacts");
  var cel = sheet.getActiveCell();    
  var val = cel.getValue();
  var row = cel.getRow();
  var col = cel.getColumn();

  if(sh.getSheetName() == "Contacts" == true){
    Logger.log('nope');
  }

  else if(sh.getSheetName() == "*** SEARCH ***" == true & row > 7){

    cel.setValue("");
    var lule = sheet.getRange(row,col).getValue();
    var line = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,1).getValue();
    sheet.getRange("A4").setValue(line)
    sheet.getRange("A5").setValue(col)

        ss.getRange(line+4,col).setValue(val);
  }
}
```

And I have a button on a sidebar that triggers this function

```
function clearCell(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("*** SEARCH ***")
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Contacts");
  var cel = sheet.getActiveCell();    
  var val = cel.getValue();
  var row = cel.getRow();
  var col = cel.getColumn();

  if(sh.getSheetName() == "Contacts" == true){
    Logger.log('nope');
  }

  else if(sh.getSheetName() == "*** SEARCH ***" == true & row > 7){

    var lule = sheet.getRange(row,col).getValue();
    var line = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,1).getValue();
    sheet.getRange("A4").setValue(line)
    sheet.getRange("A5").setValue(col)
       ss.getRange(line+4,col).clear({contentsOnly: true});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on any cell edit by user:

There is no user trigger generated for a double click on a cell.

[Sheet Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) doesn't have a method called insertRow.

An installable trigger is required for ui.prompt.

```
function editCell(e){
  //e.source.toast('flag1');
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!="*** SEARCH ***")return;
  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response=ui.prompt('Edit Contact','('+ e.value +')',ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(response.getSelectedButton()==ui.Button.OK) {
    //e.source.toast('flag2');
    var ss=e.source.getSheetByName("Contacts");
    ss.insertRowBefore(1);//added this
    ss.getRange(1,1).setValue(response.getResponseText());
  }
  else if (response.getSelectedButton()==ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    //e.source.toast('flag3');
    Logger.log('no');
  }
  else {
    //e.source.toast('flag4');
    Logger.log('nope');
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what this code is doing. Does it prompt an input box after I edit a cell or when I double click on it?

Comment: Did you install the trigger? There is no trigger generated on a double click.  Only works on user edits.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Cooper.
I'm now trying to use your code as a template to edit the cell I want base on user edits. It works fine. Now only problem, when I clear a cell using the "delete" key, when I `.getValue()` the value is not the empty cell but the text before deletion. see the UPDATED CODE